# How to make subcategories in table in R?

Tags: r

so I am trying to load this data into R for a two-way ANOVA test.
I was just wondering how to have subcategories within each dependent category. I am not asking to "fill out the table for me in R" I actually want to have an example code that might accomplish something similar to this table so that I can learn for future reference. Hope that you understand.

[image]

Comment: R's `data.frame` doesn't support sub-categories. Tables like this are generally great for *display* (reports), and as such are just aggregations of "long-format" data. As for how to render a frame into this, `gt` might be useful, as it supports "super-headers" in a sense.

Comment: Not sure if you're in need of [Subsections of an array](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#Array-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

Try the command "aggregate". That should work.